# Proving a value-wise magnitude function is differentiable

Tags: real-analysis

Let $v: \mathbb{R^n} \rightarrow \mathbb{R^m}$ be a function such that $v(y) \neq 0,\forall y \in \mathbb{R^n}$ that is differentiable at $ x \in \mathbb{R^n}$.

(a) Show that the value-wise magnitude $|v|: \mathbb{R^n} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined by $|v|(y) := |v(y)|, \forall y \in \mathbb{R^n}$
is differentiable at $x$ and that $\bigtriangledown |v|(x) = \frac{1}{|v(x)|}(\bigtriangledown v(x)^{T})v(x)$

I have no idea how to go about this problem. I don't understand the concept of a value wise magnitude function

Answer (score 0):

The "value-wise magnitude" was invented by babelfish, I guess. We are talking here about the function
$r(x):=|v(x)|$, where $v(\cdot)$ is a given vector-valued function of $x\in{\mathbb R}^n$.  Writing it out in components we have
$$r(x_1,\ldots, x_n):=\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^m v_i^2(x_1,\ldots x_n)}\ .$$
The chain rule then gives
$${\partial r\over\partial x_k}={1\over 2 r(x)}\>\sum_{i=1}^m 2 v_i(x){\partial v_i\over\partial x_k}\qquad(1\leq k\leq n)\ ,$$
and this can be written in the form
$$\nabla r(x)={1\over r(x)}\sum_{i=1}^m v_i(x)\>\nabla v_i(x)\ .$$
Personally I'd rather reserve the symbol $\nabla$ for scalar functions; hence I leave it at this.